# How to disable some items of javaFX ComboBox?

Tags: combobox, javafx-2, javafx

Can someone show me how to disable some item of my combobox (With FXML or Java code)? here is my ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox fx:id="cBox">
  <items>
    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
      <String fx:value="Easy" />
      <String fx:value="Normal" />
      <String fx:value="Hard" />
    </FXCollections>
  </items>
</ComboBox>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't found any methods that can inactive [ComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) items. You can try this work around , below code is to display sublist of items dynamically(use this idea to solve your problem).

```
private final ObservableList<String> allOptions = 
            FXCollections.observableArrayList("Easy","Normal","Hard");

   // method which returns sublist we need
    private ObservableList<String> getSubList(int start,int end) {

    final ObservableList<String> toBeDisplayedList = FXCollections
            .<String> observableArrayList();
    toBeDisplayedList.addAll(allOptions.subList(start, end));
    return toBeDisplayedList;
    }

   // now main logic
 if(displayAll) {
          comboBox.setItems(allOptions);
         }
 if(display only easy and normal) {
      comboBox.setItems(getSublist(0,2));
  } ...
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370394/javafx-combobox-change-value-causes-indexoutofboundsexception for a method to disable combo box items.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to achieve this and I came up with a custom ComboBox that disables the items I don't want the user to select. Below code shows the custom ComboBox class and how to use it.

```
    public class CustomComboBox<T> extends ComboBox<T> {

    private ArrayList<T> disabledItems = new ArrayList<T>();

    public CustomComboBox() {
        super();
        setup();
    }

    public CustomComboBox(ObservableList<T> list) {
        super(list);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {

        SingleSelectionModel<T> model = new SingleSelectionModel<T>() {

            @Override
            public void select(T item) {

                if (disabledItems.contains(item)) {
                    return;
                }

                super.select(item);
            }

            @Override
            public void select(int index) {
                T item = getItems().get(index);

                if (disabledItems.contains(item)) {
                    return;
                }

                super.select(index);
            }

            @Override
            protected int getItemCount() {
                return getItems().size();
            }

            @Override
            protected T getModelItem(int index) {
                return getItems().get(index);
            }

        };

        Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>> callback = new Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>>() {

            @Override
            public ListCell<T> call(ListView<T> param) {
                final ListCell<T> cell = new ListCell<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {

                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if (item != null) {

                            setText(item.toString());

                            if (disabledItems.contains(item)) {
                                setTextFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
                                setDisable(true);
                            }

                        } else {

                            setText(null);

                        }
                    }
                };

                return cell;
            }

        };

        setSelectionModel(model);
        setCellFactory(callback);

    }

    public void setDisabledItems(T... items) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            disabledItems.add(items[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Then add the items to disable to the ComboBox:

```
@FXML private CustomComboBox<String> customComboBox;
...
customComboBox.setDisabledItems("Item 2", "Item 3");
```

And change the class in the fxml file:

```
<views.custom.CustomComboBox ... />
```

Comment: Another (perhaps simpler?) approach in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370394/javafx-combobox-change-value-causes-indexoutofboundsexception

Comment: Worth noting, rather than set the colour from java, you're better off setting it from CSS. if you remove the line `setTextFill` and instead add a CSS item `.list-cell:disabled { -fx-text-fill: #D3D3D3 /*or -fx-opacity: 0.40*/ }`, you'll get the same effect but you wont need to hang yourself when you go to apply CSS to your application. This works because `setDisable(true)` causes the cell to become flagged with the CSS Pseudo-class "disabled".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I think that the best solution to this problem is to use the 
[setCellFactory(Callback,ListCell> value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) method of ComboBox:

```
        cBox.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param)
        {
            return new ListCell<String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
                {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (item != null || !empty)
                    {
                        this.setText(item);
                        this.setDisable(true); //or false
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

and if you want a custon ButtonCel you need to use the [setButtonCell(ListCell value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#setButtonCell-javafx.scene.control.ListCell-) Method:

```
        cBox.setButtonCell(new ListCell<String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Stringitem, boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (item != null || !empty)
            {
                this.setText(item);
                this.setDisable(true); //or false
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(EnumValues.values()));  
comboTipoOperacoes.getItems().remove(4); // remove the item 4 of Enums.
```