# JavaFX 11 ComboBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection() ends in an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, combobox, indexoutofboundsexception, javafx-11

I have a problem with JavaFX 11 ComboBoxes. I have one entry that resets the combobox. But the following Code always ends in an IndexOutOfBoundException.

```
if (combobox_class.getValue() != null && 
      combobox_class.getValue().equals("Bitte wählen ...")) {
      combobox_class.setPromptText("Bitte wählen");
      combobox_class.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
}
```

If I run this code, I'll get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: [ fromIndex: 0, toIndex: 1, size: 0 ]
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:171)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(ListChangeListener.java:243)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior.lambda$new$55(ListViewBehavior.java:281)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.callObservers(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:110)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:382)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(ListView.java:1460)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:282)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:246)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:176)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I already tried to reset the Combobox with `myCombobox.setValue(null)` but this returns the same error message.

Thanks for your help.

Marvin

Comment: Use `Platform.runLater`. See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/40467518/1943882](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40467518/1943882)

Comment: Thanks, that removes the error, but JavaFx still doesn't set the promptText